# Protobuf-net & IL2CPP - System.Reflection.Emit is not supported

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net, il2cpp

I have a problem with the protobuf-net and Android app built with IL2CPP.

Everything worked fine when I used MONO instead of IL2CPP for development. Now I need to use IL2CPP for x64 support. I didn't know `System.Reflection.Emit` is not supported with IL2CPP and protobuf-net is using it.

**Is there a way to make the protobuf-net work with IL2CPP?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got same problem on iOS. You have to compile ProtoModel before.

```
using Assembly = UnityEditor.Compilation.Assembly;
private static void BuildMyProtoModel()
{
    RuntimeTypeModel typeModel = TypeModel.Create();

    foreach (var t in GetTypes(CompilationPipeline.GetAssemblies(AssembliesType.Player)))
    {
        var contract = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ProtoContractAttribute), false);
        if (contract.Length > 0)
        {
            MetaType metaType = typeModel.Add(t, true);

            // support ISerializationCallbackReceiver
            if (typeof(ISerializationCallbackReceiver).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            {
                MethodInfo beforeSerializeMethod = t.GetMethod("OnBeforeSerialize");
                MethodInfo afterDeserializeMethod = t.GetMethod("OnAfterDeserialize");

                metaType.SetCallbacks(beforeSerializeMethod, null, null, afterDeserializeMethod);
            }

            //add unity types
            typeModel.Add(typeof(Vector2), false).Add("x", "y");
            typeModel.Add(typeof(Vector3), false).Add("x", "y", "z");
        }
    }

    typeModel.Compile("MyProtoModel", "MyProtoModel.dll"); //build model
    string protoSchema = typeModel.GetSchema(null);//content for .proto file, you can generate a proto file for a specific type by passing it instead of null
}

private static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes(IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)
{
    foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
    {
        foreach (Type type in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assembly.name).GetTypes())
        {
            yield return type;
        }
    }
}
```

Copy MyProtoModel.dll from root to Plugin folder.
And use like this:

```
TypeModel typeModel = new MyProtoModel();
```

I create small project Protobuf-net & Unity:

https://github.com/koshelevpavel/UniBufExample

https://github.com/koshelevpavel/UniBuf

But it just experimental and it don't have any documents.

Small example MonoBehaviour:

https://gist.github.com/koshelevpavel/8e2d62053fc79b2bf9e2105d18b056bc

Comment: Thank you. So far I tried the steps from [here](https://medium.com/@datdeveloper/using-protocol-buffer-in-unity-ios-android-windows-phone-8-1-4a8ea18e082b) with no luck and [Marc wrote](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/issues/351#issuecomment-363691700) that this solution is not good anymore.

Comment: I will try it and accept the answer when I get it to work. Do I need to create the TypeModel for every .proto file?

Comment: You need call typeModel.GetSchema(type), if type = null function will return .proto for whole model.

Comment: I checked Unity docs and in Unity 2017.4 that I am using the CompilationPipeline.GetAssemblies takes no parameters.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more how this script should be used? Where and when it should be called? I have no experience with UnityEditor.Compilation and I think I am doing something wrong (I am not getting the .dll file). Thanks again.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check my gist link. Take this script and paste into your project and after that select tab "Protobuf/Build model" in Unity Editor menu.

Comment: I keep getting errors in Unity Editor when using `MyProtoModel`. No errors when using `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`. The errors are of type - **Could not load file or assembly UnityEngine.UI, UnityEngine.Purchasing, Assembly-CSharp etc.** Do you know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: I case you know how to fix it, please post the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760099/custom-protobuf-net-runtimetypemodel-in-unity3d-could-not-load-file-or-assembl?noredirect=1#comment101956304_57760099). Thank you.