# Custom protobuf-net RuntimeTypeModel in Unity3D - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

I am trying to build a custom protobuf-net RuntimeTypeModel in Unity3D with this function:

```
private static RuntimeTypeModel GetModel()
{
    RuntimeTypeModel typeModel = TypeModel.Create();

    foreach (var t in GetTypes(CompilationPipeline.GetAssemblies()))
    {
        var contract = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ProtoContractAttribute), false);
        if (contract.Length > 0)
        {
            typeModel.Add(t, true);

            //add unity types
            typeModel.Add(typeof(Vector2), false).Add("x", "y");
            typeModel.Add(typeof(Vector3), false).Add("x", "y", "z");
        }
    }

    return typeModel;
}
```

The model built but when it try to use it I keep getting assembly errors in Unity Editor. - **Could not load file or assembly UnityEngine.UI, UnityEngine.Purchasing, Assembly-CSharp etc.** No errors when using RuntimeTypeModel.Default.

The strange thing is errors show only after second time I enter play mode after Unity starts. First play is without errors, when I exit the play mode still no errors in the console. Only when I enter the play mode second time the errors show and stay till I restart the Unity.

I have no idea how to improve the code to get a proper RuntimeTypeModel that wouldn't cause the errors. The code for building RuntimeTypeModel is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57721927/4841380) answer to my other question.

EDIT: 
I am not using the following lines but it doesn't matter for the issue:

```
//add unity types
typeModel.Add(typeof(Vector2), false).Add("x", "y");
typeModel.Add(typeof(Vector3), false).Add("x", "y", "z");
```

Comment: which line throws the exception? Is it perhaps the iteration of `GetTypes(CompilationPipeline.GetAssemblies())` ? i.e. if you remove *everything inside the `foreach`* (exception maybe a "write t.Name") - does it still fail?

Comment: No exceptions are thrown when running this code. I only get errors when using the actual new model built with this function. And only when I hit the play mode in the editor the second time after Unity3D starts. I forgot to mention That I save the model as a .dll file and reference it in code later.

Comment: observation: you seem to be adding the vector types multiple times; I would *expect* that to break here; tragic thing here: I understand the protobuf-net bits, but my knowledge of unity is *almost* zero.... :( this *looks* to be mostly unity related?

Comment: I am using this [code](https://gist.github.com/koshelevpavel/8e2d62053fc79b2bf9e2105d18b056bc).

Comment: Yes, I have removed these lines with vectors. I don't need them as I have my own serialization ready vector classes that I can use with protobuf-net. Unity Vector classes are difficult to serialize.

Comment: It looks like it is mostly Unity related. I can serialize/deserialize with the new model same as with default. It only seems to mess with Unity assemblies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New RuntimeTypeModel works without a problem on the android device. So at the moment I decided to change model from MyProtoModel to RuntimeTypeModel.Default when in editor with a simple `#if #else` statement.

I don't get errors in the editor and I can still use my new model on android. I am not happy with makeshift solutions and still hope for a better answer.